# php n array, n items, loop in loop

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops

i want to create this output :

```
LG
LG#Spain
LG#Spain#Paypal
LG#Spain#Paypal#Male
LG#Spain#Paypal#Female
LG#Spain#CCard
LG#Spain#CCard#Male
LG#Spain#CCard#Female
LG#Croatia
LG#Croatia#Paypal
LG#Croatia#Paypal#Male
LG#Croatia#Paypal#Female
LG#Croatia#CCard
LG#Croatia#CCard#Male
LG#Croatia#CCard#Female
LG#Czech
LG#Czech#Paypal
LG#Czech#Paypal#Male
LG#Czech#Paypal#Female
LG#Czech#CCard
LG#Czech#CCard#Male
LG#Czech#CCard#Female
Sony
Sony#Spain
Sony#Spain#Paypal
Sony#Spain#Paypal#Male
Sony#Spain#Paypal#Female
Sony#Spain#CCard
Sony#Spain#CCard#Male
Sony#Spain#CCard#Female
Sony#Croatia
Sony#Croatia#Paypal
Sony#Croatia#Paypal#Male
Sony#Croatia#Paypal#Female
Sony#Croatia#CCard
Sony#Croatia#CCard#Male
Sony#Croatia#CCard#Female
Sony#Czech
Sony#Czech#Paypal
Sony#Czech#Paypal#Male
Sony#Czech#Paypal#Female
Sony#Czech#CCard
Sony#Czech#CCard#Male
Sony#Czech#CCard#Female
```

and my code :

```
<?php

$delimiter = '#';

$keys = ['Brand','Country','Method','Gender'];
$arr[$keys[0]] = ['LG','Sony'];
$arr[$keys[1]] = ['Spain','Croatia','Czech'];
$arr[$keys[2]] = ['Paypal','CCard'];
$arr[$keys[3]] = ['Male','Female'];

$sizeofdims = sizeof($keys);
$main_key = $keys[0];


echo '<pre>';

foreach ($arr[$main_key] as $main_item)
{
    $key_handle = $main_item;
    echo "$key_handle\n";

    foreach ($keys as $i=>$k)
    {
        if ($k == $main_key)
        {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($arr[$k] as $item)
        {
            $key_current = $key_handle;
            $key_handle .= $delimiter.$item;
            echo "$key_handle\n";

            if ($i+1 == $sizeofdims)
            {
                $key_handle = $key_current;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}

echo '</pre>';
```

current output :

```
LG
LG#Spain
LG#Spain#Paypal
LG#Spain#Paypal#Male
LG#Spain#Paypal#Female
Sony
Sony#Spain
Sony#Spain#Paypal
Sony#Spain#Paypal#Male
Sony#Spain#Paypal#Female
```

Comment: Do you try anything??

Comment: Well, good luck with that. Is there a question coming or...?

Comment: We believe in you. You can do this, unless there is a question, otherwise good luck :-)

Comment: @RivnatNasah yes, i modified it..

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of a joke i will give a simpliest solution:

```
foreach ($arr[$keys[0]] as $brand) {
    echo $brand . "\n";
    foreach ($arr[$keys[1]] as $country) {
        echo $brand . '#' . $country . "\n";
        foreach ($arr[$keys[2]] as $method) {
            echo $brand . '#' . $country . '#' . $method . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

But next time try it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is a bit harder to work with. I suggest reorganising it into a multidimensional array.

```
$array = array(
    'LG' => array(
        'Neverland' => array('Pirate gold', 'Magic coins', 'Fairy dust'), ), )
        'Fantasia' => array('Gems', 'Dragon Heartstring', 'Old underwear'), ),
    ),
    'Sony' => array(
        'Neverland' => array('Pirate gold', 'Magic coins', 'Fairy dust'), ), )
        'Fantasia' => array('Gems', 'Dragon Heartstring', 'Old underwear'), ),
    ),
);
```

Now you can do the following loop

```
foreach ($array as $brand => $countries) {
    echo $brand."<br />";
    foreach ($countries as $country => $paymentMethods) {
        echo $brand."#".$country."<br />";
        foreach ($paymentMethods as $paymentMethod) {
            echo $brand."#".$country."#".$paymentMethod."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```